# Context Menu creating Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I followed this below link :
    https://codepen.io/templarian/pen/VLKZLB

But here when clicking More Option, I have to get the dynamic populated Names like

```
var Obj = [{name:"1st Item",taste:"sweet"},{name:"2nd item",taste:"spicy"}];
```

Replace of "Alert Cost" and "Alert Player Gold".

I tried but I am failed to get in dynamic looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this.... Add this code inside the function inside demo controller.

```
$scope.arr = [];
  for(let x of [{name:"1st Item",taste:"sweet"},{name:"2nd item",taste:"spicy"}]) {
    let newArr = [];
    newArr.push(x.name);
    newArr.push(function ($itemScope) {
              alert($itemScope.item.cost);
          });
    $scope.arr.push(newArr);
  }
```

And then replace the old array of **Alert Cost" and "Alert Player Gold"** with $scope.arr.

```
$scope.menuOptions = [
      ['Buy', function ($itemScope) {
          $scope.player.gold -= $itemScope.item.cost;
      }],
      null,
      ['Sell', function ($itemScope) {
          $scope.player.gold += $itemScope.item.cost;
      }, function ($itemScope) {
          return $itemScope.item.name.match(/Iron/) == null;
      }],
      null,
      ['More...', $scope.arr]
  ];
```

Voila, you good to go.
Here is working codepen example. [Working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGBJMY?editors=1010) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGBJMY?editors=1010